# How should I access a variable from javascript in PHP to perform some actions?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, reactjs

I have a file named `sample.php`, in which I have some JS code, and some PHP code. This is some sort of sample snippet of the code I have :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ThunkableWebviewerExtension = {
  receiveMessage: function(fxn) {
    var callbackFunction = function(event) {
      if (typeof fxn === 'function') {
        fxn(event.data)
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener('message', callbackFunction, false);
    window.addEventListener('message', callbackFunction, false);
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var value;
ThunkableWebviewerExtension.receiveMessage(function(message) {
  value = message;
});
  
//sending the value with ajax
$.ajax({
  url : "./sample.php", //same file
  method : "GET",
  data: {"name": value},

  success : (res) => {
    console.log(value);
  },
  error : (res) => {
    console.log(res);
  }
})
</script>

<?php
echo $_GET['name'];
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is the PHP code doesn't print anything - Are there any error/bug I need to fix? Or is there a better method for accessing a JS variable in PHP?

Thanks! :)

Comment: I can't understand your overall architecture. What's the purpose of having a script that renders a complete HTML document, together with inline scripts, and then invokes itself via AJAX? You also say the code doesn't print anything—you're writing to the browser console, is there were you're looking?

Comment: @alvaro It actually meant that the `echo` statement in PHP didn't do anything.

Comment: Where are you expecting the output from the PHP code to show up? The only place it will show is in your browser's console, because you used `console.log` with the AJAX response.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can access PHP code within in a `<script>` (without using AJAX):

```
<?php
echo"<script>";
  include ('javascriptStuff.js');
  echo'let x =  '.json_encode($phpVariable).';';
echo"</script>";
?>
```